# Declare long list in python

Tags: python, list, long-integer

`my_list = [20,21,22 ........ 60]`

in python, how can I easily declare above list with 40 elements in it. Instead of typing all the 40 elements. i know for loop can be used to append to a different list. but is there any easiest way ?

Comment: `my_list = list(range(20, 61))` this will form a list from start number up to but not including end number

Answer (score 3):

If you want a list of this specific type, you can just use

```
my_list = list(range(20, 61))
```

or if the definition becomes more complex, you can use list comprehension, like

```
my_list = [i*i for i in range(10, 20)]
```

Comment: just note that the end number is not included so these examples would go up to 59 and 19, they woudlnt include 60 and 20

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to define a range (default step size is 1 like in your example) and transform it to a list. Make sure that the last value in range() is the last value you want +1.

`mylist = list(range(20,61))`

Answer (score 0):

You can apply `for`-loop combined with `range()`-function in your code in order to append elements to `my_list`.

```
my_list = [20] # Initial list
for i in range(21, 61):
    my_list.append(i) # Append elements
```

Verify that there are 41 elements in your list (from 20 to 60)

```
if len(my_list) == 41:
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)
```